# Macbook mouse scroll direction not working

Tags: mac, mouse

I am using USB to connect with my mouse, and I wish to reverse the direction of the mouse scrolling. However, there is no change when I tick or do not tick 'Scroll direction: Natural' in System Preferences>Mouse; I have also tried to tick and not tick the 'Scroll direction: Natual' in Trackpad; it's also not working; it works for my Mac Trackpad. How can I solve it, or is there any software that can change the scroll direction also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "Scroll direction: Natural" option isn't doing anything, you can try a couple third-party apps.

Try "[Scroll Reverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/)". It's free and lets you change the scrolling direction for your mouse, trackpad, and even your Apple Magic Mouse. Just download it from the official website, install it on your Mac, and you're good to go.

Once you open Scroll Reverser, you'll see a bunch of options to customize the scrolling direction. You can choose different directions for your mouse and trackpad, and you can even turn off natural scrolling if you don't like it.

If you want more advanced customization options, you can also try "[SteerMouse](https://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/)". But just so you know, it's a paid app and might take some time to get used to.

P.S SteerMouse does not support the Apple Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad and it may not support some special buttons.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Scroll Reverser works perfectly, thank you!